# XML values into db fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have an xml which is

```
<Classes>
<Class>

<ClassID>Ledger documents</ClassID>
<Rows>
  <Row>
  <RowType>Header</RowType>
 <Cells>
<Cell />
<Cell>
  <Value>31 Jan 11</Value>
</Cell>
```

I want to insert the date value [ 31 Jan 11], group id values [7d05a53d],  2e277847 and numerals [200.56]into my db table in localserver.

How can i insert the values into Date, Groupid, Numerals fields into my db using php?

sorry for the big question.

Can somebody help me on this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP library SimpleXML to do this. Example can be found here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

```
$xmldata = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); // xmlstr can come from a string or filegetcontents

// this should be 31 Jan 11
$xmldata->Class[0]->Rows[0]->Cells[0]->Cell[1]->Value[0];
```

I would restructure your xml if you can. Give cells and rows titles that mean what the content is.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your update. I performed similar to your suggestion, but i have problems in getting the date value into db. Could you please check that and update. Thanks again

Comment: Have you did a var_dump of $xmldata to see what it contains? Here is what I got. http://pastebin.com/xR4WN768 Have you checked your SQL for errors?

Comment: The sql query works fine as of now, but i wanted to know how to get the date field <Value>31 Jan 11</Value> into db along with groupid and numerals field. Thanks

Comment: The issue got solved. Thanks